# Krusader sees doc, docx, xls, xlsx as zip archive

Tags: 17.10, mime-type, krusader

After I updated Kubuntu from version Zesty (17.04) to Artful (17.10) krusader suddenly sees office formats (doc, docx, xls, xlsx) as zip archives, where as dolphin sees them correctly. How do I fix it?

My current workaround is to set libreoffice as a zip-opening program in Krusader.

Comment: Note that docx and xlsx **are** zip-archives.

Comment: Yeap. Where as rtf is a plain text with a syntax similar to TeX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be perhaps a comment, but as mentioned [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/xlsx-and-docx-files-are-opened-as-zip-file/25814/25) deinstalling WPS solves the problem. It worked for me also. Alternatively (untested):

- Remove the 3 xml files wps-office-et.xml wps-office-wpp.xml wps-office-wps.xml from /usr/share/mime/packages/
- `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`
- Assign the .xlsx format to et, the .docx format to wps

Credit to users miku and unsocialwhoyou from mentioned forum.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Select an existing .zip file, right click and edit Properties then on the General Tab click File Type Options to bring up mime like setting for zip files.

Add wildcard *.xpi to the list of extensions alongside *.zip